# How can i always return the last series of numbers from an explode

Tags: php, explode

I have a line of code like

```
$qs = explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$pid = explode('=',$qs[1]);
```

this will return something such as 
  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "cPath"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "70_229_242_240"
}

I then have

```
$cat_ID = explode('_',$pid[1]);
```

which returns array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "70"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "229"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "242"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "240"
}

Using

```
print_r($cat_ID[3]);
```

i can get the final value of 240.

However, this only works in instances where the original string is made up of four numbers separated by underscores. In some circumstances i may have a string of three, two or even one number.

Is there a simple way to make it always fetch the last number in the string without having to code a bunch of if statements to cover situations where $cat_ID[3] or $cat_ID[2] would be empty/non existant?

I suspect the

```
$pid = explode('=',$qs[1]);
```

can be changed to take the numbers following the last underscore, but i break it every time i try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to make it always fetch the last number in the string without having to code a bunch of if statements to cover situations where $cat_ID[3] or $cat_ID[2] would be empty/non existant?

Sure;

- Explode, like you've done
- Count the number of elements, minus 1 (as it will start at index 0)

  ```
  <?php
  $cat_ID = explode('_',$pid[1]);    
  $intLastNumber = $cat_ID[count($cat_ID)-1]
  ```

#### Some example code;

```
<?php
$str = "1_2_3_4_5";
$arrNumbers = explode("_", $str);

echo $arrNumbers[count($arrNumbers)-1]; //Should be 5.
```

http://codepad.org/HEUSmLkg